# antlr plugin not recognized in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, antlr, antlr4

I Added the antlr in gradle plugins but it doesn't work

```
plugins {
    id "antlr"
    id 'war'
    id "org.gretty" version "3.0.1"
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre'
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    antlr   "org.antlr:antlr4:4.8"
}
```

but when i run gradle tasks it doesn't appear

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you need to type

```
gradle tasks --all
```

Then you'll find the antler tasks under "Other tasks".

```
...
generateGrammarSource - Processes the main Antlr grammars.
generateTestGrammarSource - Processes the test Antlr grammars.
...
```

There is more info at the Gradle [CLI documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:listing_tasks).